# I need help defining a concatenation in Coq

Tags: coq

I need to define a concatenation function, first some context, I define the set "accepts"

```
Inductive accepts : Set :=
    | True  : accepts
    .
    .
    .
    | fun_m : accepts -> accepts -> accepts
    | n_fun : nat -> accepts -> accepts
    .
```

Then I need to be able to manipulate a very specific subset of accepts: the first and last ones on the list, so True and n_fun only. I do it with a mix of inductive and record like this:

```
Inductive n_sub : accepts -> Prop :=
  | a1 : n_sub True
  | a2 : forall (n : nat )(A : accepts), n_sub A -> n_sub (n_fun n A).

Record sub : Set := mk_s{ A : accepts ; WS : (s_sub A)}.
```

As you might see this will give me strings of natural numbers followed by True, exclusively, so I want to deal with the subset of accepts that yields n ... k True. Consider I have two of this strings, I want to define the function that sends "ab... True" and "xy...True" into "ab...xy...True".

```
Fixpoint concatenate (A0 A1 : accepts)(x : n_sub A0)(y: n_sub A1):accepts:=
  match x, y with 
    | a1, q => B
    | a2 n A0 x, y => (n_fun n (concatenate A0 A1) )
  end.
```

Clearly, this doesn't work... I have tried 100 variations of this: using the accepts directly and sending the things to void, using the record inside, mixing the accepts and the sub in different variations, etc, etc... I'm just out of ideas and need someone to help me fix this concatenate, please! Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the error message you get? I had trouble making you example compile, I'm not sure I applied the right fixes. Maybe you could post a concrete working example at https://x80.org/collacoq/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to pattern-match on a thing whose type lives in `Prop` to generate something of type `accepts` which lives in `Set`. This is not allowed by Coq's type system. What you have to do is pattern-match on the things of type `accepts` and then use the properties to dismiss the impossible cases.

Here I'll use the interactive mode. This allows me to only define the part of the computation I am interested in using `refine` and leaving blank (using `_`) the parts I will deal with later on.

Because some irrelevant branches might appear when inspecting `A0`, I need to generalise the return type: instead of building an `accepts`, I'll build a proof that `n_sub a -> accepts` where `a` is whatever `A0` was matched to.

```
Fixpoint concatenate (A0 A1 : accepts)(x : n_sub A0)(y: n_sub A1):accepts.
refine
  ((match A0 as a return n_sub a -> accepts with
    | True        => fun _      => A1
    | n_fun n A0' => fun Hn_fun => n_fun n (concatenate A0' A1 _ y)
    | _ => _
  end) x).
```

I now am left with two proofs: I need to define the case I left empty but that is rather easy: the assumption `n_sub (fun_m a a0)` is contradictory! I can prove `False` by inverting it:

```
- intro Hf; apply False_rec; inversion Hf.
```

Now, I have to prove that `n_sub A0'` holds given the assumption `Hn_fun` that `n_sub (n_fun n A0')` holds true. Once more `inversion` will do the trick:

```
- inversion Hn_fun; assumption.
```

And that's it! The tricky part here is to identify the hypothesis that needs to be generalised and use the appropriate `as ... return ...` in the [dependent pattern-matching](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual020.html#sec644). The rest is made quite convenient by the use of the interactive mode and the help of `refine` to build incomplete proof terms.

Comment: Wow, I was not even aware that you could prove things from your fix point, I had always seen it as strictly a definition. I'll read more on this and refine, but your through explanation has opened many doors for me! Thank you very much, perfect answer.

Comment: Hi@gallais, I've been playing with this, and somehow when I try to use it instead of an actual concatenation I seem to just be getting that I have something type accepts, for example I get this when I print: C_1_01 = concatenate (A wt) (A w1t) (WS wt) (WS w1t) : accepts. (I defined wt and w1t before with sub, they are True and 1 True respectively) I should be getting 1True, but something weird seems to be going on...

Comment: @Sara Did you finish the proof with `Defined`? If you used `Qed` then the function is opaque and cannot reduce. Sorry, I should have mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: I did finish it with Qed, didn't know about the other option! I think this solves the problem (At least I was able to use it inside a proof the way I'd expect it to) Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is helpful to write computable predicates, rather than inductive ones (my `ok`, below, vs. your `n_sub`).

```
Inductive accepts :=
| valid  : accepts
| fun_m : accepts -> accepts -> accepts
| n_fun : nat -> accepts -> accepts.

Fixpoint ok x :=
  match x with
    | valid => true
    | n_fun _ y => ok y
    | _ => false
  end.
```

Since `ok` is computable, you can use it for all sorts of things later you might car about, but you can also use it in proofs (see below).

```
Fixpoint concat x y :=
  match x with
    | valid => y
    | n_fun z zs => n_fun z (concat zs y)
    | _ => y
  end.
```

`concat` punts on non-`ok` input. Later, I'll show a more strictly-typed version, `concatLegit`.

```
Lemma concatOk :
  forall x y,
    ok x = true -> ok y = true -> ok (concat x y) = true.
induction x; auto.
Qed.

Definition legit := { x : accepts & ok x = true }.

Definition concatLegit (x y : legit) : legit.
destruct x as [x p]; destruct y as [y q].
exists (concat x y).
apply concatOk; auto.
Defined.

Print concatLegit.

(*

concatLegit =
fun x y : legit =>
let (x0, p) := x in
let (y0, q) := y in
existT (fun x1 : accepts => ok x1 = true) (concat x0 y0) (concatOk x0 y0 p q)
     : legit -> legit -> legit

*)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this and see how it incorporates with the rest of my code. I need to use my n_sub to create a Record later, so I'll check how to get bot things together

Comment: You can define both, then prove they are equivalent, or you could simply find and replacte `n_sub` with `true = ok`. As you can from the definition of `legit`, you can put that into values of types in in `Set` or `Type`.